# Raster Geoprocessing service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, publishing

I have prepared a tool using ModelBuilder. The tool mask the raster data using the selected feature layer. It works perfectly fine in ArcGIS Desktop but when I publish it to the server and uses it for the same analysis I get an error saying that the raster file is invalid. I tried even with another dataset but it also resulted in same error

Comment: Double check your file paths and raster file types? Make sure they are compatible with being used on the server. If you have another successfully published tool that uses rasters that might be something to check against.

Comment: Just to double-check I uploaded my dataset to the server and tried to add in map. The data does not load. I guess it's the problem with my dataset.Thank you so much!